# how to move to a specific postion

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rosnode, tutorial, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All

I am using Ros to command Gazebo. I have already incorporated the DiffDrive Plugin and used it to drive it around; and I have also write a rosnode to send out cmd_vel topic command.

The next step I am looking for is to:

```
1) get the current position of my robot.
```

this probably has something to do with     tf, I will investigate in it.

```
2) move to a specific position without worrying about obstacle,
```

What I need help is number 2. Do you guys know any off-the-shelves package or tutorial I could use ?  Where should I start this?

Your help is much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63953/how-to-move-to-a-specific-postion/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For step 1: write a [tf publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

For step 2: a [motion planning library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl) with some way to detect obstacles.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-30**:
davinci, you are the man. I can't thank you enough. I will give it a try today.

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-30**:
also, do you recommend for the  "move_base" package?  have you ever used it?